# Read columns from a file into variables and use for substitute values in another file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, gawk

I have following file :
input.txt

```
b73_chr10   w22_chr9
w22_chr7    w22_chr10
w22_chr8    w22_chr8
```

I have written the following code(given below) to read the first and second column and substitute the values of first column with values in second column in output.conf file .For example, I would like to change the value b73_chr10 with w22_chr9,w22_chr7 with w22_chr10,w22_chr8 with w22_chr8 and keep doing for all the values till the end.

```
value1=$(echo $line| awk -F\ '{print $1}' input.txt)
value2=$(echo $line| awk -F\ '{print $2}' input.txt)
sed -i '.bak' 's/$value1/$value2/g' output.conf 
cat output.conf
```

output.conf

```
    <rules>
    <rule>
    condition =between(b73_chr10,w22_chr1)
    color = ylgn-9-seq-7
    flow=continue
    z=9
    </rule>
    <rule>
    condition =between(w22_chr7,w22_chr2)
    color = blue
    flow=continue
    z=10
    </rule>
    <rule>
    condition =between(w22_chr8,w22_chr3)
    color = vvdblue
    flow=continue
    z=11
    </rule>
    </rules>
```

I tried the commands(as above),but it is leaving blank file for me.Can anybody guide where I went wrong ?

Comment: Hi there and welcome. StackOverflow unfortunately is not really suitable for your kind of question (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Linux coreutils brings you `sed` and `cut` (and more... `info coreutils`) and your problem could surely be tackled with `awk`, but is too broad to be answered.

Comment: Okk..I will go through it.Thanks.Should I delete the post or edit it ?

Comment: Show two more examples what should be replaced by which string as second and third example. Do you have access to GNU sed or m4 (macro processor)?

Comment: I have just edited my post.And yes,I have access to sed and m4.

Comment: do you have any reasons to use *`bash`* only? any other language will do? `python`?

Comment: I already wrote other parts of code using bash,and I guess it will be easy easily with commands like grep,sed ,so I chose to write code in it.

Comment: Is changing the format of `input.txt` acceptable? If it is, then just change the input file into `sed` commands. Then you won't have to inline the sed commands `sed -i.bak -f input.txt output.conf`.

Comment: I didn't get your reply...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `sed` by itself is the wrong tool for this. You can however do what you're asking in bash alone:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Declare an associative array (requires bash 4)
declare -A repl=()

# Step through our replacement file, recording it to an array.
while read this that; do
  repl["$this"]="$that"
done < inp1

# Read the input file, replacing things strings noted in the array.
while read line; do
  for string in "${!repl[@]}"; do
    line="${line/$string/${repl[$string]}}"
  done
  echo "$line"
done < circos.conf
```

This approach of course is oversimplified and therefore shouldn't be used verbatim -- you'll want to make sure you're only editing the lines that you really want to edit (verifying that they match `/condition =between/` for example).  Note that because this solution uses an associative array (`declare -A ...`), it depends on bash version 4.

If you were to solve this with awk, the same basic principle would apply:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# Collect the tranlations from the first file.
NR==FNR { repl[$1]=$2; next }

# Step through the input file, replacing as required.
{
  for ( string in repl ) {
    sub(string, repl[string])
  }
}

# And print.
1
```

You'd run this with the first argument being the translation file, and the second being the input file:

```
$ ./thisscript translations.txt circos.conf
```

Comment: How to make sure that if there is only exact match,then substitution takes place for example :
b73_chr10 is changing to w22_chr90.When translation list(input.txt) has b73_chr1 w22_chr9 as one row.

Comment: @shome, I don't think you mentioned that as a criterion in your question, and `b73_chr1` was not in your list of translations. If you want to limit yourself to only one substitution per line, then you'd need either to test that a substitution had been completed, and if it had, then break out of the loop stepping through the replacement strings. If you want to avoid handling substrings, then you can "pad" the translations. If you add this to your question, I'll amend my answer to handle that requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Before you read the better solution(s), a small explanation what you did wrong.
A fixed version of your script would be

```
while read -r line; do
   value1=$(echo "$line"| awk -F" "  '{print $1}')
   value2=$(echo "$line"| awk -F" "  '{print $2}')
   sed -i "s/$value1/$value2/g" circos.conf 
done < input.txt
```

What are the changes here?

- Added `while read -r line; do ... done < input.txt`
  Your `"$line"` was  never initialised
- awk with -F" " and not \;
  You have whitespace in between
- awk without input.txt
  awk should read from the pipe, not from the file
- sed with double quotes
  The variables must be evaluated.

What's wrong with this solution?
First you must hope that the values from input.txt are sed_friendly (no slashes or other special characters).
And when you use this for large files, you will keep on looping. `awk` can handle the looping, you should avoid nesting awk in a loop.

When the input.txt is limited, you might want something like

```
sed -i -e 's/b73_chr10/w22_chr9/g' \
       -e 's/w22_chr7/w22_chr10/g' \
       -e 's/w22_chr8/w22_chr8/g' circos.conf
```

And now the comment of @alvits makes sence. Put all those sed commands in a sed-command file. When you can't change the format of input.txt, you can rewrite it in the script, but using an array as in the solution of @Ghoti is better.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.I will take care and save this answer for my future reference.

Comment: Thank you for directly addressing the OP's *actual question* of "where did I go wrong". :-) So .. +1 for you. One note though -- In his original script, I'd recommend dropping the `-F` entirely, since awk splits by whitespace by default already. Also, a lower-weight field splitting solution might be `cut`, and an even lower weight solution in bash would be to use Parameter Expansion to strip off the end or the beginning of the line.

Comment: @ghoti Yes, value="${line%% *}" is smarter, but I wanted to stick close to the OP. In a solution with the while loop I would have done `while read -r value1 value2; do`, skipping all the stripping!

Comment: @WalterA, glad we're thinking the same way, since that's what I suggested in my answer as well.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.